# Mongodb search in collection have 2 or 3 spaces

Tags: mongodb, search

let's say i have collection have column  called name
and has values like "Abcd efg" and "hij klm nop" and "qrs tuv wxw z"
so first name has 1 space and second name has 2  spaces and third name has 3 spaces

i want to search in mongodb in words just have 2 spaces how i can do it with mongodb?

Comment: this is the fastest way to do that and here is the free tier: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/regex

Comment: here is a Hadith search engine blog that might help you get started: https://azizulhaq-ananto.medium.com/mongodb-atlas-search-super-simple-very-powerful-6a2cdafa79d1

Answer (score 0):

You may do a regex search on `^[^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ][^ ]*$`:

```
db.your_collection.find({"name": /^[^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ][^ ]*$/})
```

Comment: thank you so much but how i can add this regex  ".*son.*" with "/^[^ ]*[ ][^ ]*[ ][^ ]*$/"
i mean if i want to send my name in regex   with your regex  ?

Comment: Edit your question and describe the actual problem.  I have answered the question you did ask above.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on this theme is to group the items by the number of spaces encountered, followed by an optional `$match` to show only the desired groups:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {$size: {$split: [ "$name"," " ]} }, names: {$push: "$name"} }}
]);
```

on this input:

```
{name: "A"}
 ,{name: "A B"}
 ,{name: "C D"}
 ,{name: "E F G"}
 ,{name: "E F K"}
 ,{name: "E F K  "}
 ,{name: "E M"}
 ,{name: "Z"}
```

yields:

```
{ "_id" : 5, "names" : [ "E F K  " ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "names" : [ "E F G", "E F K" ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "names" : [ "A", "Z" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "names" : [ "A B", "C D", "E M" ] }
```

Note that `E F K`   split into 5.  The more likely intended output can be achieved using `$trim`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {$size: {$split: [ {$trim: {input:"$name"}}," " ]} }, names: {$push: {$trim: {input:"$name"}} } }}
]);
```

or more compactly:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {X: {$trim: {input:"$name"}} }}
,{$group: {_id: {$size: {$split: ["$X"," "]} }, names: {$push: "$X"} }}
]);
```